# Notification crashing on emulator and device

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to get a notification to be pushed when a tickbox is checked and a button is clicked to update the record. However when this is clicked, it crashes any emulator and phone devices that is running on a version below 24.

I have got the notification to work on 24 or above which shows the implementation for the notificationcompat builder is correct but it just doesn't seem to work on any device version lower than 24.

Notification Builder:

```
public void showNotification(String tvSeriesName) {
        String notificationText = "You watched '" + tvSeriesName +
                "'; how about telling others what you thought of it!";

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Watched TV series")
                .setContentText("You've watched:" + tvSeriesName)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tv_24dp)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(notificationText))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSubText("")
                .setNumber(150)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(111, notification);
```

I am expecting the result to be a notification to pop up displaying *You watched tvSeriesName* as the title and then *how about telling others what you thought* but as I say the notification just crashes on any device version lower than 24.

Comment: Could you add the logcat of the crash, please?

Answer (score 0):

your are using code to execute Notification on api 24 and above using channels , you should use this code for api 23 and below :

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        //if you have custom view 
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), 

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_accessibility_white_36dp);
        // if you have custom view 
        mBuilder.setContent(contentView);

        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        // do not forget to mention the other info , title , text ,.....

        // unique id for NOTIFICATION_ID 
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```